# What should be deleted? If I realize a question is pointless?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, deletion

Should one remove questions that are "pointless" since the problem is much simpler than one originally thought?

Comment: I should probably recuse myself from this discussion, except to say that I wouldn't mind if you chose to delete your question. :)

Comment: Well, I feel silly now, being the cause for your having to keep the question. Perhaps I was a little trigger-happy. If you like, I can delete my answer, then you can delete your question.

Answer (score 4):

If it has been answered, the question should not be deleted out of respect for the answerers. (I think the poster can't delete questions with upvoted answers, even if s/he wants to.) Maybe the poster can explain with a comment that s/he has later realized that the question is much simpler than first thought.

But if it has no replies, I think there is no problem with the question being deleted.